# My simple if-statement works on Google and FireFox but not on safari? I am building a quiz app in React.js and the logic is pretty simple

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, conditional-statements, use-state

So the code is pretty straight forward, I am comparing the the user's answer with the correct answer. I am using useState() to manage the correct answer and I am extracting the user's answer with click events.

```
        // This is the correct answer according to the data
        let correctAnswer = await questionArray[questionNumber-1].correctAnswer;
        console.log("Correct Answer: "+ correctAnswer)
        
        // This is the answer the user choise
        let userAnswer = e.target.outerText
        console.log("User Answer: " + userAnswer)

        // This is comparing Correct Answer against the User's Answer
        if (correctAnswer === userAnswer){
            console.log('CORRECT')
        }
        else{
            // Most of the time safari will run the else statement but every once in awhile it will correctly respect the if statement
            console.log("WRONG")
        }
```

As you can Google will properly execute the if statements but Safari does not.

[image: This is Google's console]

[image: This is Safari's console]

Since the problem is specific to Safari I think it is some kind of browser issue but the code is so simple I wonder if it has to do with useState's asynchronous nature.

Any response is very much appreciated (:

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm..Strange but have you checked the length of the values?
I feel it has to do something with length of the values or the the extra 3 lines of code(Quiz.jsx line no's) that shows up in logs of safari..
Perhaps those excluded lines throw an error..

Comment: Wow, on google the lengths were the same but when I checked on Safari the lengths were different. So I removed all the spaces within the strings I was comparing and now it works on Safari, thank you!!

Comment: Glad it worked out!